# Return which field got matched in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to find out what actually got matched for a search in a specific for which the doc is returned.

Ex. I have a table index where there are  fields called table_name and column_name...
My search query is finding both those fields, now If I fire a search query and any one of them gets matched ,but I want to know what got matched .. whether its column_name or the table_name.

I am aware of the Explain API but that will require me to call another API...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call the explain API. The search API supports the `explain` flag

```
GET stackoverflow/_search?explain=true
```

This will return the `_explanation` section along with the `_source` section.

*Update*

Another solution would be to use [highlight](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-highlighting). I've used this before, for manually evaluating queries. It's an easy way to get some feedback on what matched

```
GET stackoverflow/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "FIELD": "TEXT"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, you can have the explain flag set as well