# Tag each hit with the matched value in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

*Note: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61466830/return-which-field-got-matched-in-elastic-search). But that question doesn't address my concerns.*

I have the following search request

```
GET /product/_search?explain=true
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "printer"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "computer"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "monitor"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For every hit that is returned, I want to know what should-clause values matched. I prefer explain query parameter to the highlight feature, because explain parameter's response is more structured and the client invoking the search API can reliably "tag" each hit with its corresponding should-clause values. For example, if there is a hit with both values `computer` and `monitor`, then the hit can be "tagged" with two values, `computer` and `monitor` on the client side.

I have the following questions regarding this

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. Is explain parameter only used for debugging purposes? Are there any performance impacts for using it to fulfill business use-cases like "tagging hits"?

**UPDATE:**
updating the question to address @dılosürücü comment.

Why not use highlighting?
If highlighting is used elastic will return the following response

```json
{
    "_index" : "products",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "123",
    "highlight" : {
        "content" : [
            ", some text <em>PRINTER</em> some other text, some more text",
            ",some text <em>Computer</em> some other text",
            ", some text <em>Monitor</em> some other text, some more text"
        ]
    }
}
```

The client will then have to perform a regex/string search for the content field to identify what should-clause values matched. I think the `_explanation` field in the response is more structured which would allow clients to parse the response and identify the matched values more reliably. But yes, highlighting should also work for this usecase.

Comment: do want to highlight the perform query?

Comment: @dılosürücü I have updated the question to address your comment.